# Lubuntu: How to add Thunderbird as system startup application?

Tags: lubuntu, autostart

Here is what I tried:

1) I created a folder ~/.config/autostart

2) I have copied the Thunderbird.desktop file from usr/share/applications to ~/.config/autostart

3) I have given it permissions to be able to be executed by anyone

But it still won't start on startup.

Can you help?

Answer (score 0):

According to http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXSession you can:

add @thunderbird in /etc/xdg/lxsession//autostart file

OR

do what you did and delete the "OnlyShowIn= line in the thunderbird.desktop file in your ~/.config/autostart (in my file it's the last line).
Cheers,